# Sum up the index number of arrays and send the sum to the master (C++ or Java)?

Tags: java, c++

for array `{ 24  48  27  1  5  30  40  27  31  36  29  45  45  43  10  15  50  35  40  47 }`

```
index  0- 3 ---> processor 0,  
index  4- 7 ---> processor 1,
index  8-11 ---> processor 2,
index 12-15 ---> processor 3,
index 16-19 ---> processor 4,
```

And return the sum for master to total up all.

How do I code it so it can easily be done???

```
import java.util.Random;
import mpi.*;

public class Aznin {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
            Random randomNumbers = new Random();            
            MPI.Init(args);
            int my_rank = MPI.COMM_WORLD.Rank();
            int size = MPI.COMM_WORLD.Size();
            MPI.COMM_WORLD.Barrier();
            int[] n = new int[100];
            int[] my_sum = new int[1];
            int blockNum, start, end;
            int finalSum = 0;

            // master initialize random integers and stores them
            if (my_rank == 0)   {
                System.out.println("");
                    //for 20 values produced by Random number function; but you can declare an array of 20 values; other option can read values from the file--- OK Dear Students :)                

            //how many valus you want to distribute e.g. 20 
            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)    {
                    n[i] = 1 + randomNumbers.nextInt(50);
                    System.out.printf("%d| ", n[i]);
                }
                System.out.printf("\n");
            }

            //Broadcast n from master processor to all available processors
            MPI.COMM_WORLD.Bcast(n, 0, 20, MPI.INT, 0);

            // Each processor calculates the result
            my_sum[0] = 0;
            blockNum = 20/size;     // calculates number of data blocks--- using how many CPUs i.e. Size
            start = my_rank * blockNum; // calculates for starting index for particular processor
            end = start + blockNum; // calculates for ending index for particular processor

            //Keep in mind; your approach can vary from my approach; you can create lists at run time as well --OK
            for (int i = start; i < end; i++)   {
                my_sum[0] = my_sum[0] + n[i];
            }
            System.out.println("Result from processor " +my_rank+ " = " +my_sum[0]);

            if (my_rank == 0)   {   // master processor waits for result from workers
                finalSum = my_sum[0];
                //master processor recieves result from all available worker prosessors
                for (int wproc = 1; wproc < size; wproc++)  {
                    MPI.COMM_WORLD.Recv(my_sum, 0, 1, MPI.INT, MPI.ANY_SOURCE,99);
                    finalSum = finalSum + my_sum[0];
                }
            }
            else    {   // worker processors
                // send result to master processor
                MPI.COMM_WORLD.Send(my_sum, 0, 1, MPI.INT, 0, 99);
            }

            // master processor prints final result
            if (my_rank == 0)   {
                System.out.println("Result = " + finalSum);
            }

            MPI.Finalize();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you consider explaining it a bit? What do you mean by master here?

Comment: This smells like homework. If it is, please include the full, unedited question, and tag your question with `homework`.

Comment: Master here means, if its a cluster of computers communicating amongst each other(that would be the sum up of the array), and the sum of all the array done by index should be given to the Master computer that holds all the computers together. I Do have a sample code which i just tried.. but it doesn't satisfy the needs. I will post it in a bit @Sudar

Comment: @phihag- its not homework. I wanted to solve this question.

Answer (score 0):

You could use MapReduce to sum up the array in a multi-threaded way. There are a lot of codes flying around the net for that. You just need to adopt them:

http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~gibson/mapreduceexample/main.C.html

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements aren't clear to me, not sure why you want both C++ and javascript. Anyhow, here is how to do something similar in javscript.

```
var data = [ 24, 48, 27, 1, 5, 30, 40, 27, 31, 36,
             29, 45, 45, 43, 10, 15, 50, 35, 40, 47 ];

function totalInChunks(d, n) {
  var result = [];
  var i = 0, j, len = d.length, t;
  do {
    for (t=0, j=0; j<n; j++) {
      t += d[i++];
    }
    result.push(t);
  } while (i<len)

  return result;
}

totalInChunks(data, 4); // 100,102,141,113,172
```

Whether that is useful or not I can't tell. I suppose where `t` is being calcuated you could be grouping data or objects and sending them to another processor, then collect the results at the end to collate the final result. But javascript is single threaded, so not much point in that or facilities to do it asyncrhonously, though it could be set up using *setTimeout*.

Hard to see the point though other than as an exercise in coordinating asynchronous processing.

Comment: It does makes alot of sense. I will work on it and will get back to you once i achieve what i wanted. thank you very much for your help.